# Intersection of Elements from Sets of Sets

Tags: notation

Say I have 2 sets of sets:

$$ X = \left \{  \left \{ 1,2 \right \}, \left \{ 3,4 \right \} \right \} $$
$$ Y = \left \{  \left \{ 1,3 \right \}, \left \{ 2,4 \right \} \right \} $$

I want to express that each sub-set of x has at least 1 element in common with each subset of y.

Here is what I came up with:

$$ \left \|  x \cap y \right \| \geq 1, \forall x \in X, \forall y \in Y $$

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Seems good to me

Comment: You do not need double lines, $|x\cap y|$ is ok.

Comment: Yes. Except that the notation $\|\cdot\|$ usually is for norms. I think $|x|$ is more common to denote the cardinal of $x$.

Comment: This property is also often written as: $ \forall x\in X\; \forall y\in Y:\; x\cap y\ne\emptyset $

Comment: Thanks everybody!  Good to know about single vs double lines and the alternate version by Danny.